# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code when creating a List

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, list

So when I'm trying to create A list :

```
List<CustomCohort> customCohorts = new List<CustomCohort>();
```

i'm always getting an error from this line of code.

So the it's always throwing exception :

> SqlExeception was unhandled by user code
>       An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>       Additional information: the parameterized query '(@alias int)
>            select

[exception detail click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQl8t.png)

And here is my code in the controller:

```
namespace webservices.Controllers
{
    public class CustomCohortController : Controller
    {
        private userInfoNewServiceIdentity Identity
        {
            get { return (userInfoNewServiceIdentity)Session["Identity"]; }
            set { Session["Identity"] = value; }
        }

        private string DBCONN
        {
            get
            {
                if (System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TIER") == "prod")
                {
                    return "DBCONNPROD";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "DBCONNDEV";
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the constructor of customcohort:

```
    public CustomCohort()
    {
        revisions = new List<CustomCohortRevision>();
        selectedStudents = new List<SelectListItem>();
        students = new List<string>();
    }

    public CustomCohort(int _id, string _name)
    {
        id = _id;
        name = _name;
        revisions = new List<CustomCohortRevision>();
        selectedStudents = new List<SelectListItem>();
        students = new List<string>();
    }
```

Any possible reason of this ???

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What is in the constructor of `CustomCohort`? Maybe there's something in there that causes the error.

Comment: Please share the code snippet of `CustomCohort` as well as the full error digest

Comment: Post the rest of the exception, especially the entirety of the "Additional information".

Comment: You need to show the code inside 'CustomCohort' model class and the SQL code. Otherwise, nobody can help you.

Comment: It seems your CustomCohort class is created in wrong way. Kindly try to look at more examples..And your exception message is mentioning SQLException, therefore, you'd better to show the SQL code and take care of it..Good Luck !